# A community voted to migrate my question and then a moderator disagreed and closed it - what do I do?

Tags: support, migration, migration-rejection

I asked [a question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/60257/why-did-the-mathematica-language-choose-term-rewriting-instead-of-the-lambda-cal?noredirect=1#comment127184_60257) on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

It got migrated to [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) (after [agreement from the Community](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30784837#30784837)).

[The question on the new site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119933/why-did-the-mathematica-language-choose-term-rewriting-instead-of-the-lambda-cal) got lots of attention, but was then closed by a moderator as off-topic.

I feel like I'm stuck between worlds.

My question is: **A community voted to migrate my question and then a moderator disagreed and closed it - what do I do?**

Comment: In general question seeking, why something was done by a company, is nearly impossible to answer.  The only exception is in the rare case a book was written, by somebody who was involved in that decision.  So that's likely the part of the reason your question was closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One community cannot decide for another site what is on-topic and what not. Often the migrating community does a good job finding an appropriate site, but that doesn't happen always.

The things you can do:

- Raise the topic on the site's meta the question was migrated to. Ask what can be changed to the question to make it on-topic, or ask if such question could be allowed within the scope of the site.
- Ask a question here, asking for us to recommend a site. Here there is a large group of users from across the network. They might find an appropriate site for you. Again: no guarantees the question is accepted there.

Comment: Another option would be chat. When I'm not sure about migrating a question, I've found asking the regulars in the target site's chat room to be the best option.

Comment: Indeed a possibility. Handle chat with care though since there are some users who don't like others storming in and start asking immediately.

Comment: I meant asking the regulars about whether the question would be on topic on their site, not asking the question itself. Drop a link to the question in the source site, and ask something along the lines of "hey all, would this be on topic here?".

Comment: Ah. Then I don't see why it would bother people.

Comment: Well, me neither, if that helps ;) @Yannis

Comment: @PatrickHofman then on the other hand there's users that dislike other users that storm in and then ask "Can I ask a question here?" Sites do have main chatrooms (e.g The Whiteboard, Mos Eisley, The h Bar, ...) These rooms are intended to help new users understand the site and exactly such advice should be fully supported there.

Comment: You new the chat rooms those new user cannot even use?